# Jquery giving error a.indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using WordPress in which I'm using custom script. 
Actually on WP pages which have  a particular template, I want to call a custom script.

and its giving error a.indexOf is not a function.

My custom javascript file is `cus.js`
and below is its code

```
$(window).on('load', function(){

    alert('hsdsdsi');
        $( ".disabled" ).each(function(index, element){
            alert('hsdsdsiasdasdfasfaf');


        alert(element.closest("li").attr('class'));
        });
    });
```

In functions.php

I'm using following code because I want script to function only when pages with particular template are loaded.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_load_script_for_template', 1000 );
function my_load_script_for_template( $template ){
     if(is_page_template('template-topcharts.php'))
        wp_enqueue_script(get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cus.js');

return $template;
}
```

And in another function `rehub_framework_register_scripts()` where all scripts are getting registered i have added following code

```
function rehub_framework_register_scripts() {

    wp_register_script( 'cus', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cus.js', array('jquery', 'rehub'), '1.0.0', true );
}
```

But error is coming in other files custom.js

[image]

Comment: `alert(element.closest("li").attr('class'));` - `element` is a dom object, it doesn't have a `closest()` method

Comment: then i should use $(this).closest("li").attr('class') ?

Comment: yeah, or `$(element).closest(...`

Comment: but even if I comment out this line then also this error occurs

Answer (score 0):

This error is often caused by incompatible jQuery versions.

change to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('hsdsdsi');
        $( ".disabled" ).each(function(index, element){
            alert('hsdsdsiasdasdfasfaf');


        alert(element.closest("li").attr('class'));
        });
    });
```

Comment: I have seen this an answer but I'm not adding jquery again.

Answer (score 0):

try this.,

```
function rehub_framework_register_scripts() {

    wp_register_script( 'cus', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cus.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0');
}
```